# Remove scientific notation floats in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, types, scientific-notation

I am receiving different series from a source. Some of those series have the values in big numbers (X billions). I then combine all the series to a dataframe with individual columns for each series.

Now, when I print the dataframe, the big numbers in the series are showed in scientific notation. Even printing the series individually shows the numbers in scientific notation.

Dataframe df (multiindex) output is:

```
                 Values
Item    Sub                  
A       1        1.396567e+12
B       1        2.868929e+12
```

I have tried this:

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%,.2f' % x)
```

This doesn't work as:

- it converts everywhere. I only need the conversion in that specific dataframe.
- it tries to convert all kinds of floats, and not just those in scientific. So, even if the float is 89.142, it will try to convert the format and as there's no digit to put ',' it shows an error.

Then I tried these:

```
df.round(2)
```

This only converted numeric floats to 2 decimals from existing 3 decimals. Didn't do anything to scientific values.

Then I tried:

```
df.astypes(floats)
```

Doesn't do anything visible. Output stayed the same.

How else can we change the scientific notation to normal float digits inside the dataframe. I do not want to create a new list with the converted values. The dataframe itself should show the values in normal terms.

Can you guys please help me find a solution for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I found something called [option_context for pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.option_context.html) that allows to change the display options just for the particular case / action using a with statement.

```
with pd.option_context('display.float_format','{:.2f}'.format):
    print(df)
```

So, we do not have to reset the options again as well as the options stay default for all other data in the file.

*Sadly though, I could find no way to store different columns in different float format (for example one column with currency - comma separated and 2 decimals, while next column in percentage - non-comma and 2 decimals.)*

Comment: There is a bug in the code. It should be 

with pd.option_context('display.float_format','{:.2f}'.format):
    print(fdf)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest keeping everything in a `float` type and adjust the display setting.
For example, I have generated a `df` with some random numbers.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Item": ["A", "B"], "Sub": [1,1],
                   "Value": [float(31132314122123.1), float(324231235232315.1)]})
#  Item  Sub         Value
#0    A    1  3.113231e+13
#1    B    1  3.242312e+14
```

If we `print(df)`, we can see that the `Sub` values are `ints` and the `Value` values are `floats`.

```
Item      object
Sub        int64
Value    float64
dtype: object
```

You can then call `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.1f}'.format` to suppress the scientific notation of the `floats`, while retaining the `float` format.

```
#  Item  Sub             Value
#0    A    1  31132314122123.1
#1    B    1 324231235232315.1
```

```
Item      object
Sub        int64
Value    float64
dtype: object
```

If you want the scientific notation back, you can call `pd.reset_option('display.float_format')`

Comment: Sorry. Can't lose the decimals. Have to keep at least 2 or 3 decimal points for precision.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to remove the scientific notation? Is it purely aesthetic?

Comment: The dataframe will then be printed out as a report as well as to carry out further calculations on the values. So, I need those scientific notation to be readable in normal numbers format. Pls suggest if some other way is possible.

Comment: I have edited my answer into something that might work for you.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for this. Is it possible to set the display format for just one specific column or one particular dataframe? Or it applies to everything in that file? For example, for percentages I would like normal floats with three decimals, and for others I would like floats with comma and 2 decimals. And for other dataframe, the scientific notation to continue. Is that possible?

Answer (score -1):

try `df['column'] = df['column'].astype(str)` . if does not work you should change type of numbers to string before create pandas dataframe from your data

Comment: Wouldn't conversion of numbers to string make them stored as string in the dataframe? Will I be able to do the filters and calculations on those values as string in the dataframe?

Comment: You can add a new column and store the string of numbers in it and use it for print only. or you can convert to string just before print.